# error404: Jasper Exception in Struts <s:a> tag

Tags: struts2, struts-tags

When i run my app to open the particular jsp page, it showed the following exception:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /xx.jsp (19,16) equal symbol
>   expected.

The 19th line in the jsp file is the following:

```
<s:a Admin Page>href="http://localhost:8080/MyStruts2/bloggingns/ShowBlogAdminPage"</s:a>
```

On removing the line, it worked fine.
What is the mistake in this line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's completely backwards, and it should be obvious it looks like no other JSP tag you've ever used.

```html
<s:a href="http://localhost:8080/MyStruts2/bloggingns/ShowBlogAdminPage">
  Admin Page
</s:a>
```

Unrelated, but if this is an internal link, e.g., within the same site, it makes zero sense to use (a) the full URL, it's an action, and (b) the `<s:a>` tag at all. Prefer:

```html
<a href="<s:url action='ShowBlogAdminPage' />">Admin Page</a>
```